# Fork a single page and not the entire repository

Tags: git, github

I want to copy a single page to my private repository. For e.g.

https://github.com/justmarkham/DAT4/blob/master/notebooks/08_linear_regression.ipynb

I can copy-paste this ipynb file to my server and then add and push this file to my repository.
Is there any other (simpler and easier) way?

Comment: if you only want the file - without the history and not tracking the file - I don't think there is an easier way...

Comment: I am OK with history and other tracking data. But I need only 1 page.

Comment: the question is whether you need the history... if you don't need the history nor need to track the file, copy pasting is already the easiest way AFAIK